# Late binding a variable?

Tags: variables, prolog, swi-prolog, late-binding, logtalk

I have logtalk rule to add to the prolog DB :

```
add(IF, THEN) :- new_uid(U), assertz(cond(IF, 0, U)), assertz(act(U) :- THEN).
```

it seems to work ok.. i.e. it splits the rule to TWO separate facts (which later I interpret).

```
?- rules::add(greet(X),write([hi,X])).
true

?- listing(cond).
:- dynamic cond/3.

cond(greet(_), 0, 1).

true.

?- listing(act).
:- dynamic act/1.

act(1) :-
    write([hi, _]).

true.
```

but as you see I lose the connection/unification of the variable X becomes "_" i.e. I want to to store a Variable and interpret it later
i.e. late binding.. how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your definition of the object `rules` is something like:

```
:- object(rules).

    :- uses(user, [
        cond/3, act/1
    ]).

    :- public(add/2).
    add(IF, THEN) :-
        new_uid(U),
        assertz(cond(IF, 0, U)),
        assertz(act(U) :- THEN).

    new_uid(1).

:- end_object.
```

This allows us to reproduce the results your report:

```
?- {rules}.
% [ /Users/pmoura/rules.lgt loaded ]
% (0 warnings)
true.

?- rules::add(greet(X),write([hi,X])).
true.

?- listing(cond/3).
:- dynamic cond/3.

cond(greet(_), 0, 1).

true.

?- listing(act/1).
:- dynamic act/1.

act(1) :-
    write([hi, _]).

true.
```

The problem here is that you are asserting two separated clauses but clause variables are local to the clause.

A possible solution is to make that variable explicit. For example, by modifying your code to something like:

```
:- object(rules).

    :- uses(user, [
        cond/4, act/2
    ]).

    :- public(add/3).
    add(X, IF, THEN) :-
        new_uid(U),
        assertz(cond(X, IF, 0, U)),
        assertz(act(X, U) :- THEN).

    new_uid(1).

:- end_object.
```

You would then use queries such as:

```
?- rules::add(X, greet(X),write([hi,X])).
true.

?- listing(cond/4).
:- dynamic cond/4.

cond(A, greet(A), 0, 1).

true.

?- listing(act/2).
:- dynamic act/2.

act(A, 1) :-
    write([hi, A]).

true.
```

Comment: thanks ... lets up it a noch ;) , is there a way to late-bind multiple variables, where you know the variibles at the time  when u execute rules::add() i.e. you dont know then during declaration of the rule ?  list somehow, maybe ...

Comment: Is the number of variables known in advance?

Comment: both cases .. i think if it is known i can declare add(X,Y, IF,THEN) ... if unknown add(Lst,IF,THEN)